# C# Create a virtual drive to run files from

Tags: c#, security, virtual, drive

How would I go about creating a secure virtual drive that only my program has access to and I can download and run programs.

This would include it being invisible when you look at your drives on "My Computer"

I would be using this as an anti leak for my programs. I have used the C# Assembly.Load to run certain programs, but I want to run applications that aren't .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28VS.80%29.aspx) to store data for you application. I do not think that you can download and run applications from Isolated Storage though.

You could create a Virtual Drive and mount it using the [tools available in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5291/how-to-create-a-virtual-hard-drive-in-windows-7/) and then use Windows permissions and other OS tricks to make it only accessible to you. I'm not sure about making it invisible to all users, but it could be inaccessible to anyone other than you.

If you aren't running Windows 7, I think there are other ways to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use our [SolFS OS Edition](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/). It lets you create a virtual disk with own filesystem (which has built-in encryption). When the virtual disk is mounted to UNC path, it's not visible via My Computer as it doesn't have a drive letter. Further you can restrict access to this disk to only your application and the OS itself.

Answer (score -1):

Would [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) do what you want - it does some of the things you're asking for.

Comment: I think he wants a programatic way of accessing it.